# Adjust "texture density" during UV mapping?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a wood texture such as this one.

[image]

If I UV map it to a plane of the same aspect ratio, the spacing between the wood seams will be well preserved, and I can see the same patterns.

However, when I UV map it to a twisted, arbitrary surface, the vertical seams become so dense that no other texture (such as the circular ones) is visible.

[image]

How do I have a little control over the UV mapping such that the original pattern is still visible across my surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1) classic; in edit mode select all vertices UV mapped, then open an UV image editor, select the wood texture, select all the UV grid and press S to scale it at the desired size.

2) If you don't want to modify the UV mapping, in the node material editor add an input UV node, plug it into a mapping node, and plug the latter in the vector input of the image texture node, then adjust the scale values.

Comment: Beautiful solution. I went with option 2 and got this: http://imgur.com/a/hPLYH. Absolutely amazing. May I double check with you, if I also have albedo map, selection map, etc. in my material node tree, I should feed the same mapping node to them as well right? I think this would generate the same scale for albedo, diffuse maps, and etc. Here is my node setup: http://imgur.com/a/royzm.

Comment: Yes, it's right!